# Post 2.0 is Sokahr located in any specific area, or randomly through the Oasis

Tags: diablo-iii

Sokahr the Key Warden is suppose to be found in Dahlgur Oasis. Is he found randomly within that zone, or are there certain areas where he will appear, or is more likely to appear.

Comment: Dahlgur Oasis is kind of peanut shaped (like two circles intersecting a little bit). He is in the bottom circle part most of the time, but I have seen him in the top circle on a few occasions. I'd say about 80% of the time he is in the bottom circle part of the oasis. Source: I farmed 2 hellfire rings at level 70.

Comment: I usually found him near little ponds, often at the right of bottom edge of the map. Though I don't remember seeing him more in either the top or bottom circle part of the Oasis.

Comment: Thanks. Answered my own question, based off of these answers. That's all I needed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Kevin](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/170348/post-2-0-is-sokahr-located-in-any-specific-area-or-randomly-through-the-oasis#comment230690_170348):

> Dahlgur Oasis is kind of peanut shaped (like two circles intersecting a little bit). He is in the bottom circle part most of the time, but I have seen him in the top circle on a few occasions. I'd say about 80% of the time he is in the bottom circle part of the oasis. Source: I farmed 2 hellfire rings at level 70.

From [Yellrag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/170348/post-2-0-is-sokahr-located-in-any-specific-area-or-randomly-through-the-oasis#comment230713_170348):

> I usually found him near little ponds, often at the right of bottom edge of the map. Though I don't remember seeing him more in either the top or bottom circle part of the Oasis.

Comment: Can someone tell me why is this being downvoted? It's copied from the comments, but it is not Ninjakreborn's fault that people answered in comments, rather than submitting a real answer.

Comment: It would have been a little more appropriate to ask them to write their comments in a answer rather than writing it himself. If they hadn't done so after a while (till tomorrow), then I would think the downvotes wouldn't have occured. Note: I haven't downvoted

Comment: They are more than welcome to still move their answers to the comments. Once I see the comments, get published as Answers I will pick one as answers.